# Conditionally render select boxes with autogenerated IDs

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to render different select boxes based upon the current value of another select box. The first select box is for a film name, and then the second select box shows the showings for that specific film. I could conditionally render the options inside, however, I just want to render the div as a whole.

I am doing this using the django framework. The code will produce something like this:

```
<div hidden id="Ice Age">
... Select box and options
</div>

<div hidden id="James Bond">
... Select box and options
</div>
```

I then want to access this div and remove the hidden tag, displaying the select box. I am however having issues with my javascript, as I cannot use query selector on the item, as the IDs are created conditionally.

Here is my attempt:

```
filmSelection.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const filmSelectionTemp = document.querySelector('#film'); // Get the film drop down
    let temp = '#' + event.target.value // Create the ID of the currently selected film
    const result = document.querySelector(temp); // Select that div
    result.classList.remove('hidden') // Remove hidden tag
})
```

This tells me : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

Not really sure what is going on.

New to javascript so pls be nice :)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. `id` attribute values cannot contain (white)spaces. Try to convert your id value to, for example: `ice-age` and `james-bond`. `querySelector` returns `null` when the queried element has not been found. Be sure to check if the `result !== null` before assuming it is an actual found element.

Comment: Hi, i have just changed this and it is still not showing?

Comment: You mentioned a select box. Do the values of the `<option>` elements  in that select element match the `id` attribute values? If this still doesn't work, help us by creating a runnable snippet (`<>` icon in the question editor) in which we can experience your issue.

Comment: You use hashtag prepend on `let temp = '#' + ...` but the hashtag is not apart of the ID itself

Comment: @mardubbles it is if you use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which supports CSS selectors to find elements, in contrast to [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: I see on that part (as in thanks for the correction), @EmielZuurbier

Comment: By the way, I see that you use `result.classList.remove('hidden')` to remove the `hidden` attribute. But this removes the hidden *class* from the `class` attribute. If the `result` is an HTML element, then it has a [`hidden`(boolean) property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden)  which allows you to manipulate the [`hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden). Try `result.hidden = false`.